# Can't edit input with initial value in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I work on a project in React, and I have an input in a table for the quantity of a product I want to buy, and I can't change the value on the web page.

If I delete the value property, I can modify the value, and I think I typed something wrong. Can somebody help me with how to have an initial value equal to `1` and still be able to update it?

```
<input
  type="text"
  id={"cantitate_" + index}
  value={1}
  onChange={(e) => changeQuantity(e.target.value, index)}
/>
```

changeQuantity is a function where I try to calculate something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using  `defaultValue` instead of `value`, since I assume from the comment that you are not implementing a [controlled form](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

```
<input
  type="text"
  id={"cantitate_" + index}
  defaultValue={1}
  onChange={(e) => changeQuantity(e.target.value, index)}
/>
```

Comment: i don't have any variable quantity saved. All I want is that the value to be 1 for start and to can change the value

Comment: In this case use `defaultValue` instead, I just edited my answer.